# Installing third party software alongside my VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation

I want to create a setup for my VB.NET project which i already know how to do. However one fault with my standard setup is that although it installs my program correctly, my program requires some third party PDF creator software to be installed on the same computer that it is running on.

My question is, is there a way to create a setup for my program where i can give the user the option of ticking a check box if they also want to install the third party software required, and if so how would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, which software do you use?

I have good experience with http://www.jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php. Maybe you should check if the extentions solving your problem.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: Inno Setup is an external setup creator. You just give him your executable and the PDF creator as additional file.

Comment: The setup exe for my project or just the exe to run it?

Comment: Inno Setup create an install routine. This includes your executable of your own project of course. Sorry I think I didn't get the question?

Comment: basically i've made a program in visual studio but in order for it all to function correctly the user needs to have a piece of software called PDFCreator installed too. I was wondering that is there a way to create a setup for my VB program that also installs the PDFCreator?

Comment: Well simply check the registry for the installed software. I thought you wanted to isntall a software with you own tool. I missunderstood you, sorry.